# How to get the eq5d command working in Stata 12

Tags: stata

The `eq5d` command in Stata computes an index value from individual responses to the EQ-5D quality-of-life instrument, as it is described here http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0220

But the `eq5d` command is not recognized by Stata 12.1 for Windows (32 bits) installed in my laptop. Is it a version issue? Or is there a change in the command name?

Does someone have any idea how to get the `eq5d` command working in Stata 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a version problem as the minimum requirement of **eq5d** is Stata 9, so version 12 is fine. However, it is a user-written command, so you will need to install it. To do so, type in Stata **findit eq5d**; after that it is just a matter of clicking on the appropriate links.